# How to create azure SQL database connection using Protractor?

Tags: protractor, azure-sql-database

How to create azure SQL database connection using Protractor ? Can anyone help with code written in Typescript ?

Comment: Is this [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/azure-sql/database/connect-query-nodejs?tabs=windows) helpful to you?

Answer (score 0):

You can use tedious, mmsql, sequelize and other libraries to operate the sqlserver database in nodejs.

For example:

MSDBClient.ts

```js
import mssql = require('mssql');

// 定义数据查询回调接口
export declare type OnQueryCallback = (err: Error, rc: any) => void
export declare type OnExecCallback = (err: Error, rc: boolean) => void

export class MSSQLDBClient {
  // url
  constr: string;

  constructor(username: string, password: string, host: string, port: number, dbName: string) {
    this.constr = this.constr = `mssql://${username}:${password}@${host}:${port}/${dbName}`;
    mssql.connect(this.constr).then(function () {
      console.log('----------------');
      console.log('-login success-');
      console.log('----------------');
    }).catch(function (err) {
      console.log(err);
    })
  }

  public async query(strSql: string, cb: OnQueryCallback) {
    try {
      await mssql.connect(this.constr).then(function() {
        new mssql.Request().query(strSql).then(function(result) {
          // console.log(result);
          if (cb) cb(null, result);
        }).catch(function(err) {
          console.log(err);
          if (cb) cb(err, null);
        });
        // Stored Procedure
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (cb) cb(err, null);
    })
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
      if (cb) cb(err, null);
    } 
  }


  public async exec(strSql: string, cb: OnExecCallback) {
    await mssql.connect(this.constr, function () {
      mssql.query(strSql, function (err, data) {
        if (err) {
          if (cb) cb(err, false);
        } else {
          if (cb) cb(null, true);
          mssql.close();
        }
      });
    }
    );
  } 
}
```